# Change color and Font Size icons Ion-toolbar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to change the color and the size of the letter inside the ion-toolbar but without success, what I've tried so far:

```
ion-toolbar {
    --background: var(--custom-primary); //works
    --color: #FFFFFF; //works letters, not icon

    ion-buttons {
        font-weight: bold; //works
        --icon-font-size: 10px !important;
    }

    ion-back-button {
        --icon-font-size: 30px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly style your toolbar in the template. E.g.:

```
<ion-toolbar color="green">
...
</ion-toolbar>
```

Check out these docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced#themes. Theming ionic core components like the ion-toolbar is a little different.